# Pairing more than two lists using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list

I would like to know how to pair more than two lists.

I know this is easy to do using .zip function, but how do I pair a third or more lists?

```
var list1 = ee.List(['20190101T160509_20190101T160509_T17RNJ',
                     '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RLH',
                     '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMJ',
                     '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMK']);
var list2 = ee.List(['17RNJ','17RLH','17RMJ','17RMK']);
var list3 = ee.List([1,2,3,4]);

var paired = list1.zip(list2);
print(paired);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a sequence of index numbers and then map over that list:

```
var paired = ee.List.sequence(0,list1.length().subtract(1),1).map(function(i){
  return [list1.get(i),list2.get(i),list3.get(i)]
})

print(paired)
```